# How to read pdf custom properties using Powershell

Tags: pdf, powershell, metadata, properties

I am trying to read custom Document properties of PDF file using PowerShell script. I could able to read Microsoft documents, but I am unable to read PDF metadata. Your reply is highly appreciated.

I can read docx properties like below through Powershell as below:

```
$application = New-Object -ComObject word.application
$application.Visible = $false
$document = $application.documents.open(“C:\test\Classified Document.docx”)
$binding = “System.Reflection.BindingFlags” -as [type]
$customProperties = $document.CustomDocumentProperties
```

But the above code is not working for PDF files.

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @DavidPostill he might be looking for a single command solution/asking if such a thing exists. He didn't ask for a script, he said he's trying to write one. I think.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read out internal pdf creation/modified date with Windows PowerShell?](http://superuser.com/questions/764513/how-can-i-read-out-internal-pdf-creation-modified-date-with-windows-powershell)

Comment: Yes,I just want to know, if it's possible with Powershell script. If I know, it's possible, I can hire a person for this job.